# xlsxwriter pandas frame: to highlight rows if there are blank cells within a column

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-highlighting, xlsxwriter

I'm having a pandas frame with column T that has some blank cells. I want to highlight any rows that have blank cells

I've been trying to use .format but it only highlight the blank cells instead of the whole row.

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:T18', {'type':'no_blank'
                                       'format':green_fmt}

)
```

Expected: the whole row gets highlighted in light green
Actual Results: only the blank cells got highlighted

Comment: Try writing it into a csv file

Comment: Is there a way to write into xlsx file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If blanks values are missing values use pandas [styles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) with custom function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'T':[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 5],
                   'A':range(4),
                   'B':list('abcd')})
print (df)
     T  A  B
0  NaN  0  a
1  NaN  1  b
2  1.0  2  c
3  5.0  3  d

def highlight(x):
    c = 'background-color: lime'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    m = x.isna().any(axis=1)
    df1 = df1.mask(m, c)
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, jezrael. Is there a way to use the xlsxwriter engine to do this since most of my code is based on this specific engine?

Comment: @DatNguyen - Not sure, I check [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) and seems not supported.

Comment: Yeah, I was also checking it but saw that it only highlighted cells instead of a whole row

Comment: Actually, I think I can find the index of nan rows and then use set format to color those

Comment: @DatNguyen - yes, by `idx = df.index[df.isna().any(axis=1)]`

Comment: Then use loop and function worksheet.set_row() and color it :)))

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Build a function which highlights row if NaN is found.

**2.** dataframe.style.apply(function_name, axis=1)

```
# Function to color entire row
def color(row):
    if row.isnull().values.any() == True:
        return ['background-color: red'] * len(row)
    return [''] * len(row)

# Create a dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1":col1, "col2":col2, "col3":col3})

# Empty values
col1[3], col2[0] = None, None

# Apply the function
data.style.apply(color, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, TheSHETTY. Since I’m highlighting it and exporting it to xlsx file, so pandas alone does not support this operation. Therefore, I’m using the xlsxwriter engine to do this. I’ve just come up with trying to index the row number of those blank and then use that to set color :)

Comment: So applying `.to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)` will help?

Comment: I’m not sure about the openpyxl engine since I haven’t had a chance to use it regularly. But for the xlsxwriter engine, the way of finding index and use set_row works really well

Comment: Check this [notebook](https://gist.github.com/shravankumar9892/44d5fe69abe9b72615d16563a46fccc8). openpyxl engine is also giving correct result

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

# Create a test dataframe (borrowed by jezrael)
df = pd.DataFrame({'T':[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 5],
                   'A':range(4),
                   'B':list('abcd')})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Define the format for the row
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})

# Grab the index numbers of the rows where specified column has blank cells (in this case column T)
rows_with_blank_cells = df.index[pd.isnull(df['T'])]

# For loops to apply the format only to the rows which have blank cells
for col in range(0,df.shape[1]): # iterate through every column of the df
    for row in rows_with_blank_cells:
        if pd.isnull(df.iloc[row,col]): # if cell is blank you ll get error, that's why write None value
            worksheet.write(row+1, col, None, cell_format)
        else:
            worksheet.write(row+1, col, df.iloc[row,col], cell_format)

# Finally output the file
writer.save()
```